# How do you validate that someone signed something with a private key

Tags: encryption, aes

So I'm currently trying to understand a soup to nuts path of how public private keys work.

So far I think I understand how the keys are generated and how messages can be encrypted with them.

The thing I'm having trouble finding info on though is, how does one validate that something was signed by someone else's private key with their public key? I thought that you encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key.

Can someone point me at some material to understand how you can validate a signature?

This question comes from an attempt to understand how you can validate that someone signed a blockchain transaction with their private key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signing is different from encryption (well, you still use encryption, but anyway)

For RSA (Thanks Michael):

To digitally sign, you make a hash of the data and then use the private key to encrypt the hash. You then send this along with the message you signed.

The recipient can confirm it was signed by you by decrypting using the freely available public key and comparing the hash to one they generate from the message.

Comment: Although 'blockchain' without qualification usually means bitcoin and bitcoin doesn't use RSA, it uses ECDSA (on the curve commonly called secp256k1) for which both signing and verification are almost completely different, and there is no encryption of any kind.

Comment: Dave - blockchain definitely does not usually mean bitcoin. It doesn't even mean cryptocurrency.